# Question regarding exporting of mx files

Tags: export

I want to export a bunch of data to `.mx` files. So I created a function

```
str = (Print["a\n"]; Print[a]; Print["\nb\n"]; b);
```

where `a` and `b` are two lists..Then I did

```
Export["eg.mx",str]
```

and then when I tried to import

```
Import["eg.mx"]
```

it is giving only `b` list and not list `a`. What is wrong with my function?

Comment: Try `str = Grid[{{"a =", a}, {"b =", b}}]`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 7):

It is a common mistake to assume something *has to be printed* in order to *be there somehow*. I cannot express this better, but something like this must be the case.

You are wrong. Printing is a function that prints something on the screen. You cannot *print something into a variable*. The solution is very simple:

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {3, 4};

str = {a, b};
Export["eg.mx", str]
```

and then you can do

```
{a2, b2} = Import["eg.mx"]
```

Of course, you don't need `str` at all. You can simply use `Export["eg.mx", {a,b}]`.

Regarding your comment

> I need an output that looks something like "a ={1,2} ,b={3,4}" .But if we do by this method we are getting a list of two {{1,2},{3,4}}. Although we can parse from that, but is there any way we can just export that in that format i have given.

I'm really confused. First, you don't create any *output* that looks like anything when you export to `mx` because `file.mx` is a binary format. You cannot read it.

I have another idea what you could mean by *"just export that in that format i have given"*. You can use `DumpSave` to store variables. To be exact, you store symbols and there associated values. Therefore, consider this example:

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {3, 4};
DumpSave["eg2.mx", {a, b}]
```

What you did here is really store the variables `a` and `b`. Therefore, let's clear them in your current session

```
ClearAll[a,b]
```

Now, you can call

```
Get["eg2.mx"]
```

and magically the variables `a` and `b` are defined again and have their values:

```
a + b
(* {4, 6} *)
```

Comment: Hi @halirutan...I need an output that looks something like "a ={1,2} ,b={3,4}" .But if we do by this method we are getting a list of two {{1,2},{3,4}}. Although we can parse from that, but is there any way we can just export that in that format i have given

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I get what you mean, because words like *parse* and *format* just don't make sense in this Mathematica context. Nevertheless, I have updated my answer at the end with a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code using an example list, this is what I got:

```
a = {1, 2};
b = {3, 4};
str = (Print["a\n"]; Print[a]; Print["\nb\n"]; b);

a

{1, 2}

b
```

So I'm guessing that this should work (I'm just adding on actually printing b):

```
str = (Print["a\n"]; Print[a]; Print["\nb\n"]; Print[b]);
```

This worked for me when I did it. Is this what you meant? This is the output I received:

```
a

{1, 2}

b

{3, 4}
```

Comment: Hi @nbingo..thank you for your reply but that is not what i wanted. In fact if i remove the semicolon at the end of statement of str, we can get "a" as well as "b". But  I need a way to export the contents in that manner to an mx file and import them back in the same format.